# Warning: findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode. findDOMNode was passed an instance of Transition which is inside StrictMode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-strictmode

I am trying to use a function as a prop inside a component and this component is a child of another component. But the function is not working.? Can I know why. This is the warning i am receiving in the console.

> Warning: findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode. findDOMNode was passed an instance of Transition which is inside StrictMode. Instead, add a ref directly to the element you want to reference

This is my code

```
class Todo extends Component {
  state = {
    show: false,
    editTodo: {
      id: "",
      title: "",
      isCompleted: false
    }
  }
  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({ show: false })
  }
  handleShow = () => {
    this.setState({ show: true })
  }
  getStyle () {
    return {
      background: '#f4f4f4',
      padding: '10px',
      borderBottom: '1px #ccc dotted',
      textDecoration: this.props.todo.isCompleted ? 'line-through'
        : 'none'
    }
  }
  //this method checks for changes in the edit field
  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ title: event.target.value })
    console.log(this.state.editTodo.title);
  }

  render () {
    //destructuring
    const { id, title } = this.props.todo;
    return (
      <div style={this.getStyle()}>
        <p>
          <input type='checkbox' style={{ margin: "0px 20px" }} onChange={this.props.markComplete.bind(this, id)} /> {''}
          {title}
          <Button style={{ float: "right", margin: "0px 10px" }} variant="warning" size={"sm"} onClick={this.handleShow}>Edit</Button>{' '}
          <Button style={{ float: "right" }} variant="danger" size={"sm"} onClick={this.props.DelItem.bind(this, id)}>Delete</Button>
        </p>
        <Modal show={this.state.show} onHide={this.handleClose}>
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title>Edit your Task!</Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body >
            <FormGroup >
              <Form.Control
                type="text"
                value={this.state.editTodo.title}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
              />
            </FormGroup>
          </Modal.Body>
          <Modal.Footer>
            <Button variant="secondary" onClick={this.handleClose}>
              Close
                          </Button>
            <Button variant="primary" onClick={this.handleClose}>
              Save Changes
                          </Button>
          </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    )

  }
}
```

Comment: The `findDOMNode` error looks like it's happening inside a library, it's not in your code. That is not a relevant warning for your issue I don't think. Which part of the code that you wrote is not working as expected?

Comment: the handleChange method is not working as i expected

Comment: If you're using `react-boostrap`, the [issue](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/5075) was fixed on version v2 alpha.

Comment: This could also be a library issue in many cases, e.g., at the time of writing this comment, if you're using AntD, you could face this warning. See: https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/26136

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The `setState` call looks like it's being written to the wrong place. Make sure it's on the `editTodo` object:

```js
    handleChange = (event) => {
        this.setState(state => ({
          editTodo: {
            ...state.editTodo,
            title: event.target.value,
          },
        }));
    }
```

Comment: tanx man. This solves part of my problem. Now i can get the expected output from the function. But the warning is still there.  Anyways thank you!.

Comment: You shouldn't need to worry about that warning. I'm guessing it's coming from whatever library you're using for the `Modal` and `Button` components (maybe react-bootstrap?). It's warning that the functionality is deprecated, but that means it still works fine but will be removed in a future release of React.

Comment: @RossAllen `css-transtion` from `react-transition-group` create a same warning

Comment: The answer really has nothing to do with the question asked in the title, your comment is far more suitable as an answer, and the answer is far more suitable as a comment IMHO.

Answer (score 69):

If you're using a Modal or Carousel from `react-bootstrap` a workaround is disabling the **animations**. Turning them off makes the warning disappear.

For Modals:

```
<Modal animation={false}>
    <Modal.Header closeButton>
        <Modal.Title>Title</Modal.Title>
    </Modal.Header>
    <Modal.Body>
        Content
    </Modal.Body>
</Modal>
```

For Carousels:

```
<Carousel slide={false} fade={false}>
    <Carousel.Item>
      Scene 1
    </Carousel.Item>
    <Carousel.Item>
      Scene 2
    </Carousel.Item>
</Carousel>
```

I know it'd fit better as a comment once it doesn't answer the OP question, but I don't have a reputation enough to do so and maybe it helps someone.

**EDIT**: [This was fixed on v2 alpha](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/5075#issuecomment-850127642)

Comment: Just a note: the warning seems to disappear when you run the built version.

Comment: And if you're using OverlayTrigger from react bootstrap, setting `transition={false}` does the trick.

Comment: Another note: If you have multiple react-bootstrap modals on the same page, *all* need to have anmiation={false}

Comment: This solution is safer than disabling strict mode, I no longer have the Error

Comment: facing this issue reactstrap modal when I toggle modal is throws this error. animation={false} and transition={false} didn't solve it

Answer (score 67):

In index.js change `<React.StrictMode><App /><React.StrictMode>` to `<App />` and you will not see this warning. Please note that strict mode helps you with

- Identifying components with unsafe lifecycles
- Warning about legacy string ref API usage
- Warning about deprecated findDOMNode usage
- Detecting unexpected side effects
- Detecting legacy context API

Please refer to https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html before removing it.

Comment: Better to fix the root cause

Comment: how to fix this root cause?

Comment: Usefull solution when the warning comes from third party libraries.

Comment: What about Next.js ?
In next.config.js
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: false,
}
Not helps

Comment: it doesn't resolve anything, just hide the warning

Comment: A library might be using CSSTransition from ReactTransitionGroup which uses findDOMNode to find it's child element to animate. The solution is to get a `ref` of the child node yourself and pass it to the CSSTransition element as a nodeRef property. Then CSSTransition won't need to call findDOMNode.

Answer (score 42):

The response of @Ross Allen is not related to the basic problem (the warning), it resolved a syntax problem in the code.

The response of @Ali Rehman is more related to the warning, but also it's not resolving **correctly** the problem, it only **hides** it so that the warning does not appear no more. Why not, if we don't care about deprecations !!

Yes, the problem is coming from the React.StrictMode:

```
<React.StrictMode>
 <App />
</React.StrictMode>
```

StrictMode is a tool for highlighting potential problems in an application. It activates additional checks and warnings for its descendants, such as:

- Identifying components with unsafe lifecycles
- Warning about legacy string ref API usage
- Warning about deprecated findDOMNode usage
- Detecting unexpected side effects
- Detecting legacy context API

As the error backtrace is not fully given in the question, I guess the problem is related to a **Warning about deprecated findDOMNode usage**, because of referencing to elements in the render methods:

```
<Modal show={this.state.show} onHide={this.handleClose}>
      <Modal.Header closeButton>
        <Modal.Title>Edit your Task!</Modal.Title>
      </Modal.Header>
      <Modal.Body >
        <FormGroup >
          <Form.Control
            type="text"
            value={this.state.editTodo.title}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
        </FormGroup>
      </Modal.Body>
      <Modal.Footer>
        <Button variant="secondary" onClick={this.handleClose}>
          Close
                      </Button>
        <Button variant="primary" onClick={this.handleClose}>
          Save Changes
                      </Button>
      </Modal.Footer>
    </Modal>
```

When the component is rendered, so the modal has been also rendered, and we try to change states of the component, the component (and so the modal) will re-render, and in this stage the modal can not have access to the states.

The solution to resolve the warning is by using [React refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html). Refs helps to access DOM nodes or React elements created in the render method.

Comment: Can you provide some example, please? What you said makes sense to me. I tried to set `ref={myRef}` to the Modal and `target={myRef}` to the Button but I still get the warning. I'm using a function component with hooks. Thanks!

Answer (score 26):

I'm not sure if it's helping when using the material-ui library but in many cases this can help:

```
const nodeRef = React.useRef(null);
return <div>
  <CSSTransition ... nodeRef={nodeRef}>
    <div ref={nodeRef}> ... </div>
  </CSSTransition>
</div>
```

Comment: sweet, this actually got rid of the warning. Would be helpful if u can add the explanation to why this might work!

Also, Wrapping in a additional div and attaching a ref might not be possible in cases where one can't add the wrapper due to styling issues. `React.forwardRef` helps in that case as explained in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63205067/10208226)

Comment: First thank you for the insights. 
1. In the docs it's says that when nodeRef prop is passed, node is not passed, and this is give you the ability to pass your ref element inside the CSSTransition.
2. The component wrapper div is not necessary. it can be a Fragment.

Comment: This is the correct answer when using custom transitions.

Comment: Correct answer when using `react-transition-group`

Answer (score 14):

In **Semantic UI React**, this is a [known issue](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/pull/4233), most of their components are still using `findDOMNode()`. This is being fixed in the [Semantic UI React v3 PR #4233](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/pull/4233) where all these components will be updated to use `React.forwardRef()`.

At first I thought I was doing something wrong and spent quite some time investigating, only to find it was a known issue.

One interesting edge case for [PR #4233](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/pull/4233) which might be helpful here was that all components could be converted to function components *except* for the `<Dropdown>` component. For this they wrap the component with a function component using `forwardRef` and then pass an `innerRef` prop to the class component (via [PR commit diff](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/pull/4233/commits/e3315918173ab9b1e507330203480b904ce6d621#diff-fb4ce0f2e7774c9377c564009db97821e4bbdfc369b462bab22b80e9048a6660)):

```
const Dropdown = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return <DropdownInner {...props} innerRef={ref} />
})

class DropdownInner extends Component {
  searchRef = createRef()
  sizerRef = createRef()
  ref = createRef()
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks man... I already spent lot of time to find your comment :)

Answer (score 6):

This is an issue of MaterialUI library, and there's a [temporary solution](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/13394#issuecomment-815452717) here before the new MaterialUI v5 is officially released

Comment: My issue came from MUI's Collapse component, so this is very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen this error before ,when i used react-bootstrap and react-router-dom along side
each other .
i replaced

```
<Link to="/foo">sth</Link>
```

with

```
 <LinkContainer to="/foo/bar">
  <Button>Foo</Button>
</LinkContainer>
```

and there is no need to use Link for NavLink

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution to this type of scenario is to wrap your component with a DOM element that you can actually attach a ref to it. For example:

```
import React, { createRef, Component } from "react";
import ChildComponent from "./child-component";

class MyComponent extends Component {

 componentDidMount() {
  const node = this.wrapper.current;
  /* Uses DOM node  */ 
}

wrapper = createRef();

render () {
return (
  <div ref={this.wrapper}>
    <ChildComponent>{this.props.children}</ChildComponent>
  </div>
 );
 }
}

export default MyComponent;`
```

Answer (score 0):

A similar issue:
Below solved the problem:

In the `ReactDOM.render()` function, change

from

```
  <React.StrictMode>
    <SnackbarProvider>
          <App/>
    </SnackbarProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
```

to

```
  <SnackbarProvider>
    <React.StrictMode>
          <App/>
    </React.StrictMode>
  </SnackbarProvider>
```

NOTE:  `SnackbarProvider`  & `React.StrictMode` tags are reversed.

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue is not an error, but is a deprecation warning. the library component still works, but uses a feature that will no longer be available in future releases. so the library must be updated to use another function to replace the old one.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Ref

For example, with the React Draggable library:

const MyComponent = props => {
const nodeRef = React.useRef(null);
return (

Example Target

);
}

Answer (score 0):

Based on @kernel-james comment to OP his solution worked for react-transition-group library.

```
const parentDivRef = React.useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

<Transition nodeRef={parentDivRef} >
<div ref={parentDivRef}> {/* content that needs animation */} </div>
</Transition>
```

Answer (score -4):

To fix this issue just remove React.StrictMode from index.js where you access the dom root id, that will fix it.

Instead of this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Use this line:

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />,document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: This isn't a fix if strict mode is desired.