# Material-UI Accordion findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

When I expand or open the Accordion that is provided by Material-UI, I get findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode error in console.

```
 return (   
  <Accordion>
      <AccordionSummary
        expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
        aria-controls="skills"
        id="skills"
       >
        <h3>Skills</h3>
      </AccordionSummary>
      <AccordionDetails>
        This is skills....
      </AccordionDetails>
  </Accordion>
)
```

Comment: Is the question called [Warning: findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode. findDOMNode was passed an instance of Transition which is inside StrictMode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60903335/warning-finddomnode-is-deprecated-in-strictmode-finddomnode-was-passed-an-inst) helping?

Comment: I don't think so. Cause I'm using material ui for this component.