# findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode. findDOMNode was passed an instance of Transition (created by MUI Backdrop) which is inside StrictMode

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm getting the following warning:

> Warning: findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode. findDOMNode was
> passed an instance of Transition which is inside StrictMode. Instead,
> add a ref directly to the element you want to reference. Learn more
> about using refs safely here:

> ```
> in div (created by Transition)
> in Transition (created by ForwardRef(Fade))
> in ForwardRef(Fade) (created by ForwardRef(Backdrop))
> in ForwardRef(Backdrop) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Backdrop)))
> in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Backdrop)) (at CircularProgressOverlay.tsx:20)
> in CircularProgress (at VpmsSpinnerMat.tsx:7)
> in VpmsSpinner (at ProductCreate.tsx:19)
> in div (at ProductCreate.tsx:18)
> in ProductCreate (created by Context.Consumer)
> in Route (at ProductMain.tsx:36)
> in Switch (at ProductMain.tsx:34)
> in Router (created by HashRouter)
> in HashRouter (at ProductMain.tsx:33)
> in Provider (at ProductMain.tsx:32)
> in ProductMain (at App.tsx:9)
> in div (created by Styled(MuiBox))
> in Styled(MuiBox) (at Box.tsx:32)
> in Box (at App.tsx:8)
> in App (at src/index.tsx:9)
> in StrictMode (at src/index.tsx:8)
> ```

And here is the component:

```
import React from "react";
import './spinner.css';
import {Backdrop, Theme} from "@material-ui/core";
import {createStyles, makeStyles} from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
    createStyles({
        backdrop: {
            zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer + 1,
            color: '#fff',
        },
    }),
);

export default function CircularProgress(props: any) {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const wrapper= React.createRef();

    return (
        <Backdrop className={classes.backdrop} open={true} ref={wrapper}>
            <div className="lds-dual-ring"/>
        </Backdrop>
    )
}
```

`findDOMNode` is caused by Transition.js (created by Backdrop) in MUI. Is there a way to remove the warning without disabling StrictMode? I tried with `ref={wrapper}`, but no effect.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Warning: findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode. findDOMNode was passed an instance of Transition which is inside StrictMode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60903335/warning-finddomnode-is-deprecated-in-strictmode-finddomnode-was-passed-an-inst)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I applied this solution:

```
import React from "react";
import './spinner.css';
import {Backdrop, Theme} from "@material-ui/core";
import {createStyles, makeStyles, unstable_createMuiStrictModeTheme, ThemeProvider} from "@material-ui/core/styles";

// FIXME. To be fixed in future versions of MUI. Not advised for use in Production: https://material-ui.com/customization/theming/
const theme = unstable_createMuiStrictModeTheme();

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
    createStyles({
        backdrop: {
            zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer + 1,
            color: '#fff',
        },
    }),
);

export default function CircularProgress(props: any) {
    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <Backdrop className={classes.backdrop} open={true}>
                <div className="lds-dual-ring"/>
            </Backdrop>
        </ThemeProvider>
    )
}
```