# React-Transition-Group: findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode

Tags: reactjs, react-transition-group, react-animations

I am using the animation library `react-transition-group` in react for animating a TODO list using `<TransitionGroup>` and `<CSSTransition>` as shown below

```html
<ul>
   <TransitionGroup className="todo-list">
      {incompleteTodos.map((task) => (
      <CSSTransition key={task.id} timeout={500} classNames={styles}>
         <li key={task.id}>
            <TodoTask
               todo={task}
               onClick={(todo) =>
            toggleTodo({ data: todo })}
            />
         </li>
      </CSSTransition>
      ))}
   </TransitionGroup>
</ul>
```

But I am getting the error in the console as below:

[image]

I read about using `nodeRef={nodeRef}` on the `CSSTransition` element mentioned in this [official changelog](https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group/blob/1fd4a65ac45edd2aea3dec18eeb8b9c07c7eb93f/CHANGELOG.md#features) and [git issue](https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group/issues/668) as shown below but then it started behaving weird i.e. some of the elements are not appearing properly in UI as shown in the screenshot below code snippets:

```js
const nodeRef = React.useRef(null)
```

and

```html
<ul>
   <TransitionGroup className="todo-list">
      {incompleteTodos.map((task) => (
      <CSSTransition
         key={task.id}
         timeout={500}
         classNames={styles}
         nodeRef={nodeRef}
         >
         <li key={task.id} ref={nodeRef}>
            <TodoTask
               todo={task}
               onClick={(todo) =>
            toggleTodo({ data: todo })}
            />
         </li>
      </CSSTransition>
      ))}
   </TransitionGroup>
</ul>
```

This screenshot is taken after applying `nodeRef` in `CSSTransition`
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Warning: findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode. findDOMNode was passed an instance of Transition which is inside StrictMode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60903335/warning-finddomnode-is-deprecated-in-strictmode-finddomnode-was-passed-an-inst)

Comment: Maybe check out [this Changelog description](https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group/blob/8dc9ad8d9412878a40312e418d389bf97f3794b8/CHANGELOG.md#440-2020-05-05)?

Comment: @edemaine Tried this but my code has Transition and CSSTransition, didn't work

Answer (score 2):

You need to make a separate `ref` for each of the `CSSTransition`s.  The easiest way to do that is to make a custom component:

```js
<ul>
   <TransitionGroup className="todo-list">
      {incompleteTodos.map((task) =>
        <TransitionTodo key={task.id} todo={task}/>}
  </TransitionGroup>
</ul>
```

```js
function TransitionTodo({todo}) {
  nodeRef = useRef();
  return (
    <CSSTransition
       timeout={500}
       classNames={styles}
       nodeRef={nodeRef}
     >
       <li ref={nodeRef}>
          <TodoTask
             todo={todo}
             onClick={(todo) =>
               toggleTodo({ data: todo })}
          />
       </li>
    </CSSTransition>
  );
}
```