# Why does React app fail when I reload page

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am busy learning javascript, and it, as well as react, nodejs and npm are all brand new concepts to me, so bear with me.

I have managed to piece together an application which returns the weather for my location by following this tutorial: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/learn-react-by-building-a-weather-app/

I run npm and then I am able to view the executed app on localhost:3000/

When I make changes to the .js application (I use atom), npm compiles the new code and it works perfectly.

But when I reload the web page it doesn't work (returns nothing).

Looking at the console in Chrome, when I do a compile, it immediately gets my location and the API call to openweathermap works (it includes the location in the call of course).

But when I reload the page, it seems like the location is not successfully fetched, and then obviously it cannot return anything. What's weird is that it seems to attempt it 3 times, and the second time it works, but the first and third time it fails.

Here is the piece of code where the issue seems to lie and I also attached an image of what the app looks like when it WORKS, and what the console shows when it does NOT work (when reloading).
[image: console when I reload]
[image: when it works]

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        setLat(position.coords.latitude);
        setLong(position.coords.longitude);
      });

      await fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/weather/?lat=${lat}&lon=${long}&units=metric&APPID=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(result => {
        setData(result)
        console.log(d)                      // (GL)
        console.log("Latitude is:", lat)    // (GL)
        console.log("Longitude is:", long)  // (GL)
        console.log(result);
      });
    }
    fetchData();
  }, [lat,long])
```

Comment: Stop working in [Strict-mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html)... it's useless and problematic

Comment: Makes **no sense** writing `await fetch` when you're using the *promise* syntax `then`... pick one of the code styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the [react-strict](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) wrapper component.

Also - makes no sense writing `await fetch` when you're using the *promise* syntax then...

You need so split the logic within the `useEffect` because you are setting a state within the `getCurrentPosition` callback, and at the same time listen to a state change in the dependency array of that useEffect...

```js
// this useEffect will only fire when the component mounts (once)
useEffect(() => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(location => {
        // you should validate the response before setting the state...
        setLat(location.coords.latitude);
        setLong(location.coords.longitude);
    });
}, [])

// this useEffect will be called one the component mounts + when any dependency changes (lat/long)
useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/weather/?lat=${lat}&lon=${long}&units=metric&APPID=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(result => {
            setData(result)
            console.log(d)                      // (GL)
            console.log("Latitude is:", lat)    // (GL)
            console.log("Longitude is:", long)  // (GL)
            console.log(result);
    });
}, [lat, long])
```

Even though this is correct, this is considered bad code, and should be split between separate files for dealing with the API/actions/utility methods..etc.

Comment: I have (as a starting point) removed strict mode. I still wanted to work through the rest of your feedback to make the changes (and I still will), but after removing strict mode everything works fine! can you perhaps explain why?

Comment: The error message is very clear & helpful: ***"findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode"*** and you should have Googled that to learn more about it and could have found a [wealth of answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60903335/104380). I suspect it's a 3rd-party package which is using deprecated code. Impossible to know which from your screenshot. (you probably need to check the console in development-mode and not production-code to understand from the stack where is the root cause)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your fetchData function is an async function. So when you call fetchData, you'll need a .then() to make sure that it gets the result. Also your useEffect inner function should be async

```js
useEffect(async () => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        setLat(position.coords.latitude);
        setLong(position.coords.longitude);
      });

      await fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/weather/?lat=${lat}&lon=${long}&units=metric&APPID=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(result => {
        setData(result)
        console.log(d)                      // (GL)
        console.log("Latitude is:", lat)    // (GL)
        console.log("Longitude is:", long)  // (GL)
        console.log(result);
      });
    }
    fetchData().then(result => {
        //do stuff (or await this fetch data)
    });
  }, [lat,long])
```

Comment: **No** it's not that at all. incorrect. no need for `async` in `useEffect(async () => {`